# Populating Autocomplete list with new tags

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I'm using Lucee 5.x and Maria DB (MySQL).

I have a user supplied comma delimited list. I need to query the database and if the item isn't in the database, I need to add it.

**user supplied list**
`green
blue
purple
white`

**database items**
`black
white
red
blue
pink
orange
lime`

It is not expected that the database list would grow to more than 30 items but end-users always find 'creative' ways to use the tools we provide them.

So using the user supplied list above, only `green` and `purple` should be added to the database.

Do I compare the user supplied list against the database items or vice versa? Would the process change if the user supplied list count exceeds what is in the database (meaning if the user submits 10 items and the database only contains 5 items)? I'm not sure which loop is the better way to determine which items are new. Needs to be in cfscript and I'm looking at the looping options as outlined here (https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/coldfusion/cfscript/)

FOR Loop
FOR IN Loop (Array)
FOR IN Loop (Query)

I tried MySQL of NOT IN but that left me with the existing database values in addition to the new ones. I know this should be simple and I'm over complicating this somewhere and/or am too close to the problem to see the solution.

Comment: You may be able to use an UPSERT.   `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (42,'MyDupeValue') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE myName='MyDupeValue';`  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: I thought about that but if the tag exists, there isn't anything to update. Would this still work?

Comment: May have found a solution.  https://cflib.org/udf/ListDiff

Comment: You might be able to use `INSERT... IGNORE` to skip the extra update, but there are issues with it suppressing errors that you may actually want.

Comment: Since this is an operation that the database is capable of handling, my initial thought would be to go with the database's solution. If you do it in code, you'll have to make multiple trips to the database to do what you need to do. Plus, you have a huge potential for dirty data, ie someone else inserts a conflicting record while you are stripping duplicates from an early query to do your new insert.

Comment: @Shawn I do prefer to offload heavy lifting for the DB when appropriate. Given that, you think the UPSERT is still a better solution than the UDF I found? Also, the autocomplete is tied to the user, not the entire system so Jack and Jill have different autocomplete data (just more info to help with the puzzle).

Comment: I still think the database would be a better place for this kind of operation. IO and Network become a much bigger issue in Production when you make multiple trips to the database. And again, you can end up with locking or polluted data when doing transformations like this in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

- get a list with existing items from database
- append user supplied list
- remove duplicates
- update db if items were added

---

```
<cfscript>

    var userItems = '"green","blue","purple","white"';
    var dbItems = '"black","white","red","blue","pink","orange","lime"';
    var result = ListRemoveDuplicates( ListAppend(dbItems, userItems));

    if (ListLen(result) neq ListLen(dbItems)) {
      // update db
    }

</cfscript>
```

> Update (only new items)

```
<cfscript>

    var userItems = '"green","blue","purple","white"';
    var dbItems = '"black","white","red","blue","pink","orange","lime"';
    var newItems = '';

    ListEach(userItems, function (item) {
        if (not ListFind(dbItems, item)) {
          newItems = ListAppend(newItems, item);
        }
    })

</cfscript>
```

***trycf.com gist:***
(https://trycf.com/gist/f6a44821165338b3c10b7808606979e6/lucee5?theme=monokai)

Comment: Your solution is more of a UNION.  I’m looking for new items only. The reason is I need to perform additional processing to the new items. HTH.

Comment: Updated the answer for new items.

Comment: ListEach - I've not seen that function before!

Comment: Oh, I did know about ListEach, just forgot that I knew it! :)

Comment: For my application, I used `ListFindNoCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Again, since this is an operation that the database can do, I'd feed the input data to the database and then let it decide how to deal with multiple keys. I don't recommend using CF to loop through your values to check them and then doing the `INSERT`. This will require multiple trips to the database and then processing on the application server that isn't really needed.

My suggestion is to use MariaDB's `INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` syntax. This will also require that whatever field you are trying to insert on actually has a `UNIQUE` constraint on it. Without that constraint, then your database itself doesn't care if you have duplicate data, when can cause its own set of issues.

For the database, we have

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (mycolor varchar(50)
  , CONSTRAINT constraint_mycolor UNIQUE (mycolor)
) ; 

INSERT INTO t1(mycolor)
VALUES ('black'),('white'),('red'),('blue'),('pink'),('orange'),('lime') 
;
```

The ColdFusion is:

```
<cfscript>

myInputValues = "green,blue,purple,white" ;

myQueryValues = "" ;

function sanitizeValue ( String inVal required ) {
    // do sanitization stuff here
    var sanitizedInVal = arguments.inVal ;
    return sanitizedInVal ;
}

myQueryValues = myInputValues.listMap( 
    function(i) {
        return "('" & sanitizeValue(i) & "')" ;
    } 
) ;

// This will take parameterization out of the cfquery tag and
    preform sanitization and validation before building the 
    query string.

myQuery = new query();
myQuery.name = "myQuery";
myQuery.setDataSource("dsn");

sqlString = "INSERT INTO t1(mycolor) VALUES " 
    & myQueryValues 
    & " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mycolor=mycolor;" 
;

myQuery.setSQL(sqlString);
myQueryResult = myQuery.execute().getResult();

</cfscript>
```

First, build up your input values (`myInputValues`). You'll want to do validation and sanitization on them to prevent nastiness from entering your database. I created a `sanitizeValue` function to be the placeholder for the sanitization and validation operations.

`myQueryValues` will become a string list of the values in the proper format that we will use to insert into the database.

Then we just build up a `new query()`, using `myQueryValues` in the `sqlString` to get our query. Again, since we are building a string for multiple values to `INSERT`, I don't think there's a way to user `queryparam` for those `VALUES`. But since we cleaned up our string earlier, it should do much of what `cfqueryparam` does anyway.

We use MariaDB's `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` syntax to only insert unique values. Again, this requires that the database itself has a constraint to prevent duplicates in whatever column we're inserting.

For a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4308da3addb9135e49eeee451c6e9e58

This should do what you're looking to do without beating up on your database too much. I don't have a Lucee or MariaDB server set up to test, so you'll have to give it a shot and see how it performs. I don't know how big your database is or will become, but this should still query pretty quickly.